# What is the baby-step to derive this?

Tags: probability, statistics, time-series

Could somebody help me with this one quickly? My midterm is coming in 3 hours. I wonder how to go from the first line to the second line? How does (Z of t)^2 suddenly become (Z of t-1) ?

Thank you

[View picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCMZP.png)

Comment: you are not giving enough information to receive any help.. your question is missing context.

Comment: I'm sorry. {Z of t} follows i.i.d N (0,1) . Let {Y of t} = the first line in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(Y_t \leq 0 ) &= \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (Z_t^2 - 1) \leq 0\right)\\
& = \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} Z_t^2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq 0\right)\\
& = \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} Z_t^2  \leq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(  Z_t^2  \leq  1\right)\\
& = \mathbb{P}\left(Z_{k}^2  \leq  1\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where the last equality holds for any $k = 1,2,3,...$. In particular it holds for $k = t-1$. This is due to the i.i.d. assumption on $Z$.

In other words, because $Z_r$ and $Z_s$ are both standard normal random variable (for any values $r$ and $s$) it holds that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\left(  Z_r^2  \leq  1\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z_{s}^2  \leq  1\right).
\end{equation}

Comment: The "for any k" part was what confused me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the square of number is less than one, the number must lie between $-1$ and $1$, that is, its absolute value is less than one:
$z^2<1\iff -1<z<1\iff |z|<1$.

Comment: Yes, I understand this concept. What I don't understand is how to go from the first line to the second line. Please help